# Javascript Delay

Tags: javascript, browser, delay, settimeout, setinterval

I understand that Javascript does not have a delay(500) method, which would delay execution for 500 milliseconds, so I have been trying to get around that by using setTimeout and setInterval.

```
for(var i =0; i< 10; i++){
    /* Animation Code */
    var doNothing = function(){var m =5;}
    setTimeout(doNothing, 50); 
}
```

However, this does not seem to work. I essentially want some code that stops the execution for *n* milliseconds and then continues execution.

Comment: _"However, this does not seem to work"_ please expand, how is it not working

Comment: It works... it's just your timeout is set to 50 milliseconds instead of 500.

Comment: What environment are you running this code in? Is it in a browser or somewhere else? [`setTimeout`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setTimeout.html) is actually part of the DOM, not JavaScript itself. Some JavaScript environments provide their own implementation of `setTimeout`, but not all do.

Comment: @UselessCode I have the document saved as an html file (I use textWrangler as the application) and run it by opening the file in chrome.

Comment: Think outside the box. The key point in your question is *stops execution, then continues execution*. It assumes you want to **preserve the state** between stop/continue (in your case, it's the state of the animation, although `i` variable is also a part of it). This is something that other answers are not currently addressing. Here is how it can be done: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21360405/1768303.

Comment: @Noseratio this has proven to be a bit of a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/133242), which is why the answers don't necessarily match up with the current version.

Comment: @MattBall, indeed it has. The OP didn't even bother to vote or comment on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Practically speaking, you can't do this. Deal with it and find a callback-based way instead. Typically this means putting *everything* that should happen after the delay in the callback itself.

For example, you can't do this to make `baz` wait:

```
foo();
setTimeout(function() {
  bar();
}, 500);
baz();
```

so you do the only thing you can:

```
foo();
setTimeout(function() {
  bar();
  baz();
}, 500);
```

Comment: To add more to this... refactor in a new way of thinking.  Don't simply have a ton of code in callbacks in callbacks in callbacks in settimeout callbacks.

Comment: @Brad you're absolutely right. [Promises](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) are a good starting point.

Comment: So why does setTimeout not wait the specified time when executing? Is there something peculiar about its behavior of which I should be aware?

Comment: `setTimeout` works. Trust me. It _does_ wait the specified duration of time before executing the callback you pass it. What it does not do is block other execution, and that is by design.

Answer (score 2):

**The setInterval() Method** wait a specified number of milliseconds, and then execute a specified function, and it will continue to execute the function, once at every given time-interval.
**Syntax**

```
window.setInterval("javascript function",milliseconds);
```

The window.setInterval() method can be written without the window prefix.

The first parameter of setInterval() should be a function.

**How to Stop the Execution?**
The clearInterval() method is used to stop further executions of the function specified in the setInterval() method.

**Syntax**

```
window.clearInterval(intervalVariable)
```

The `window.clearInterval()` method can be written without the window prefix.

To be able to use the `clearInterval()` method, you must use a global variable when creating the interval method:

```
myVar=setInterval("javascript function",milliseconds);
```

Then you will be able to stop the execution by calling the `clearInterval()` method.
[good refrence](http://www.sean.co.uk/a/webdesign/javascriptdelay.shtm)

Comment: There is a subtle but **[important difference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21360405/1768303)** between *delay* and *interval*.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval()` - executes a function, over and over again, at specified time intervals

> To pass a function as a string, be sure to append the function name with parentheses.
>   window.setInterval("someFunction()", 5000);
>
> When passing a function pointer, do not include the parentheses.
>   window.setInterval(someFunction, 5000);
>
> var timer_id=setInterval(doNothing,500);

If you want to stop the execution
make the `timer_id` variable global

> clearInterval(timer_id);

Comment: There is a subtle but **[important difference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21360405/1768303)** between *delay* and *interval*.

Answer (score 1):

If you came from the language/framework/API background, where you could suspend the execution with something like [`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or process user input synchronously with something like [`DoEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it won't work in JavaScript.

There is no way you can block the JavaScript event loop with something like this, for a good reason: UI responsiveness. In JavaScript, everything is asynchronous. You can use `setTimeout` to do something upon a timer event, but the user is still able to access the UI between the timer events or even navigate away from the page.

To address your code fragment, what you are looking for is called an asynchronous state machine. It allows to **preserve the state** of the code between stop/continue (in your case, it's the state of the animation, although `i` variable is also a part of it):

```
(function()
{
    var i = 0;
    var nextStep = function()
    {
        if (i<10)
        {
            /* Animation Code */
            i++;
            setTimeout(nextStep, 500); 
        }
    }
    nextStep();
})();
```

It will be much easier to code when all browsers support the new `yield` keyword:

http://pag.forbeslindesay.co.uk

On a side note, some other answers suggest using `setInterval`. There is a subtle but important difference between *delay* and *interval*. Delay is the **time between two steps**. Interval is the time **since the previous step started**. If each step of animation takes 200ms, and you use the interval of 500ms, the actual delay between two steps will be 300ms, not 500ms as probably expected.

Answer (score 0):

Much cleaner and readable code would be if you use RxJS

Here is an example:

```js
Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .take(10)
  .subscribe((x) => console.log(`${x}: ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.lite.min.js"></script>
```

> interval - is a time delay between your animation calls. In my example
>   it's 1000ms
>
> take - number of times to execute subscribe - is function
>
> that will be called every 1000ms for 10 times (in your case it will be
>   your animation code)

Answer (score 0):

Here some something that could help.

```
function delay( s , callback )
{
    var fct_ref = "tmp_" + Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 6).toUpperCase();       
    var tmp_fct = ( callback !== undefined ) ? callback.toString().match(/^[^{]+\{(.*?)\}$/)[1] : "";

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","<div id='"+fct_ref+"' style='background-color:transparent;color:transparent;position:absolute;top:"+window.scrollY+"px;left:"+window.scrollX+"px;opacity:1;transition:all "+s+"s'>-</div>");

    var func = new Function("return function transition"+fct_ref+"(e){ e.target.removeEventListener('transitionend' , transition"+fct_ref+", false ); "+tmp_fct+" ; document.getElementById('"+fct_ref+"').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('"+fct_ref+"')); };")();

    document.getElementById(""+fct_ref).addEventListener("transitionend", func , false );
    document.getElementById(""+fct_ref).offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById(""+fct_ref).style.opacity="0";
}

delay(1, function() { console.log("ANIMATION_1"); } );  
delay(3, function() { console.log("ANIMATION_3"); } );  
delay(5, function() { console.log("ANIMATION_5"); } );
```